# AppCenter Xamarin.Forms iOS test calabash build error

Tags: xamarin.ios, ui-testing, calabash, calabash-ios

I try to test my Xamarin.Forms iOS App on AppCenter. The things that i do for that are the following:

1. Install calabash
2. Build the App
   When the app is going to be build the error message:

> The type or namespace name 'Calabash' does not exist in the namespace

comes.

In my App the Xamarin.Testclout.Agent is as NuGet Packes installed.

I dont have any idea what the problem here can be, so please can your give me some new points of view?

Comment: No ideas? Anybody?

Comment: uninstall and install the Xamarin.TestCloud.Agent package for the iOS project